# Simple MPI program fail with large number of processes

Tags: c, linux, mpi

This is my code:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

   int  numtasks, rank; 

   MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
   // the code fail with or without printf
   printf ("Number of tasks= %d My rank= %d\n", numtasks,rank);

   MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

And this is how i run it and the output:

```
$ mpirun -n 160 ./mpi_example1
[proxy:0:0@ubuntu] send_cmd_downstream (./pm/pmiserv/pmip_pmi_v1.c:80): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:0@ubuntu] fn_get (./pm/pmiserv/pmip_pmi_v1.c:349): error sending PMI response
[proxy:0:0@ubuntu] pmi_cb (./pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:327): PMI handler returned error
[proxy:0:0@ubuntu] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (./tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:0@ubuntu] main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:226): demux engine error waiting for event
[mpiexec@ubuntu] control_cb (./pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_cb.c:215): assert (!closed) failed
[mpiexec@ubuntu] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (./tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[mpiexec@ubuntu] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (./pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:181): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@ubuntu] main (./ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:405): process manager error waiting for completion
```

When I run the code with -n 128 or lower, it works fine. I also tried to run the code on a 32 cores x 8 nodes computer and able to run up to -n 192, when i try -n 224 it fail...

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Your root process (rank 0) exits before all others have properly started, I believe. Adding `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);` before `MPI_Finalize();` should fix it, if that is the case. Could you try that, please?

Comment: Thank you I'll try it and answer asap!

Comment: @Nominal Animal Sadly, I tried the method you suggest but the same error occurs... :(

Comment: @NominalAnimal Doesn't `MPI_Finalize` implicityl call `Barrier`? [Cray materials](http://www.nersc.gov/assets/NUG-Meetings/MPINERSC-Cray.pdf) say it does, but it might be implementational detail.

Comment: @luk32 Personally I think MPI_Finalize should do that too. So I really don't know what's going on here. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Phuocdh90 I've read [MPI 3.0 Standart](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf) and there is no mention of implicit barrier during finalize so it probably is an implementational detail. Anyways it is not problem in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be related to the maximum number of processes that can be spawned by your shell. How to modify this setting depends on the type of shell and on the operating systems. If you are using cshell or tcshell you can verify your current setting using from the common line the "limit" command. Changing the setting may be done both at the user level or at the root level (there are both soft and hard limits).

Comment: I tried ulimit -n 2048 on ubuntu terminal, and it seems that the command itself works (as I tried ulimit -n 256 and the program couldn't run with -n 128, the error code was "open file limit"). But the problem was not solved...

Comment: Then, you may also need to modify the setting for the maximum number of file descriptors: try something like (for c and tc shell) limit descriptors 24576.

Comment: I also hope that is the problem, but I must run the code on a super computer at my school, and I only allowed to use a few commands on that computer (as my professor don't want students to cause any damage to the computer). He only said that the code should work on the computer when I asked him about the problem. I'm at a completely lose...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive answer, but its way too long for a comment.

I took a look at the source of the failed assert. The [codebase](https://github.com/adk9/hydra/) is slightly different, but I think it's close enough. Your error says assert failed at line 80 while [here](https://github.com/adk9/hydra/blob/master/pm/pmiserv/pmip_pmi_v1.c#L66), the assertion `HYDU_ASSERT(!closed, status);` lies in line 82.

The offending call is located at line 77:

`status = HYDU_sock_write(fd, cmd, strlen(cmd), &sent, &closed, HYDU_SOCK_COMM_MSGWAIT);`

Now, the code for [`HYDU_sock_write`](https://github.com/adk9/hydra/blob/f0ce4451f04d26c55e2f59f12b59d222da838a2c/utils/sock/sock.c#L265) says that the `closed` flag will be set and the function will abort operation when

`write(fd, (char *) buf + *sent, maxlen - *sent);` @line 278 fails with `errno == ECONNRESET`.

Now [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html) documentation for `write` says: *"[ECONNRESET]
A write was attempted on a socket that is not connected."*

Are you sure the network is working fine? It seems like sockets get disconnected.

Comment: The error above is from running the code on a Ubuntu VMWare (2 processors, 2 cores each), not on the 32 core x 8 nodes super computer. Is that have any related to the problem? Because I don't understand how network causes problem here.

Comment: And also, when I ran the code with low number of processes (128 and bellow on my computer), no matter how many time I run the code, it always execute correctly...

Comment: To me it looks like system/hardware error. I have no idea why socket would get disconnected, but it looks this is the root of program failure. I am not sure what can cause `ECONNRESET`. Maybe you could ask some specialists on hydra developers forums/lists. After all it's hydra calls which fail.